# Best place to ask science related question

Tags: support, asking-questions, site-recommendation

Is there any place on Stack Exchange to ask science related questions ,

like

> E = MC<sup>2</sup>, what does it really mean?

or

> We know that oxygen is needed for various life forms; why are other gases like CO<sub>2</sub> and nitrogen not?

Comment: There is physics.stackexchange, but your first question is not a good one because it is answered in every popular science book/website ever written. Really. The second question *may* fit on biology.stackexchange - read their FAQs first, but I think I've seen similar questions there.

Comment: Beyond school, `science` becomes too broad a term.

Comment: Your second question is based on a wrong assumption, both CO2 and N2 are used by certain organisms (plants and nitrogen-fixating bacteria, respectively)

Comment: @MadScientist It's still potentially a good question though. A good answer could start like that...

Comment: @MadScientist all those questions some samples only , my actual question vary.

Answer (score 8):

"Science" is simply too broad of a field.  There are many different types of science fields, and many different stack exchange sites that all fit into the scope of "science".

Here is a (non-inclusive) list of some sites that all represent [mostly or entirely] "science" questions:

- Stack Overflow
- Web Masters
- Game Development
- Programmers
- Physics
- Chemistry
- Biology
- Electrical Engineering
- Android
- DBA
- Computer Science
- Libraries and Information Science
- Robotics